Why does iics generate a temporary parameter file starting with s_mtt_ when executing taskflow?
I created a mappingtask, used in-out param, and referenced the parameter file. But when I executed taskflow, I found that several param files starting with s_mtt_ were generated in the parameter folder.
I think that there is no need to test the number of articles, because the number of articles has increased at a certain time, so the number of articles has increased in number, so the number of articles has increased in number, and the number of articles has increased.

Can I ask you to rework the question a bit? It is not clear. Additionaly, please name the files that get created. Share the list for review. Check the contents.
